# ASCII files get erased after opening in Python

Tags: python, csv, ascii

I started learning Python recently and came across of the following problem
I open a ASCII fine for reading, say data.txt and try to print it to the screen. I am using this code:

```
f = open("E:\ASCII\data.txt", "r")
  for line in f:
  print(repr(line))
```

This shows nothing on the screen, and the file gets erased of all the imformation contained, and gets 0kb of size. 
I'm using Python 2.7.9 64-bit on Pycharm.
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Are you using you are using `r`?

Comment: The code you show cannot do that. It won't erase the file. Are you  sure you are reading the correct file? Also, you probably want to escape your ``\`` backslashes or use a raw string literal (`open(r"E:\ASCII\data.txt", "r")`)

Comment: I supposed you should use open("E:\\ASCII\\data.txt", "r")

Comment: You are either opening with `w` or you actually have empty files.

Comment: Note of the above work, my file gets erased. I'm using Python 2.7.9 64-bit in PyCharm.

Comment: Apparently, there was a PyCharm error. I had another code lines above that opened the file in w mode. Problem solved. Thank you!

Comment: lol I like how you blame pycharm as if it wrote the code ;)

Comment: It's my error, I admit. I thought that marking the lines with the red dot, stops them from running, as said in the description. :3

Comment: That's a break point for the debugger (as said in the description). If you just run your code instead of debugging it it won't stop.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Not sure about the deletion, but this should print what you want

```
with open('E:\ASCII\data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.read().splitlines():
        print repr(line)
```

Comment: There's no need to call `f.read().splitlines()`